# How to log error with unique id and send that id in rest response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I am working on spring boot application where I want to log exception with unique id in log file and send that id in response to user, so user can provide that id to support team and they can get log from file by searching this id.

I am using @ControllerAdvice to handle error globaly I am printing log like below
I didn't configure logger yet, just using with default seeting

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

  protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);
  logger.error("Error",ex);
```

ex- is exception object

Its printing log like below

```
2018-04-06 17:45:37.566 ERROR [micro-app,912f0faf43795429,912f0faf43795429,false] 8660 --- [nio-9530-exec-1] d.d.c.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler : Error

javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: entity.notFound
    at com.ge.managers.impl.AssetCompanyRelationshipManager.get(AssetCompanyRelationshipManager.java:139) ~[classes/:na]
```

micro-app is my application namebut what is 912f0faf43795429,912f0faf43795429 these id here? is it unique for each error, how i can access them and send in response.

If its not possible to use this id as unique referece error Please suggest possible approch.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like some kind of processing context id, e.g, for every request a unique id is generated and attached to the logging context. So it gets logged along with every message produced during this request's processing cycle. You'll need to check your app's logging config to understand exactly what it is.

Comment: Try something like `httpsession.getId() + Long.toString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong())`.  More importantly, don't make support manually dig through log files.  Log to a database or use a log aggregation tool.

Comment: @ jingx as mentioned in question i didn't use any custom logging config,actually i just added slf4j dependencies and used it, there is no log4j config or logback xml so its difficult to understand what are those ids

Answer (score 1):

Consider using https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/ (distributed tracking)

If you do not want new library and you just want annotate each log with unique ID then Nested Diagnostic Context (NDC) or Mapped Diagnostic Contexts (MDC) will help you. You need to genearate unitque id (UUID is sensible default) for each request as soon as you receive request, and put this value in MDC. Implementation details depend on logging framework you use

Example for logback: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Example for log4j: http://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-ndc-log4j

Note that note that a child thread does not automatically inherit a copy of the MDC/NDC. Therefore if you pass processing to new thread you need to pass and set again values in MDC/NDC (it uses ThreadLocal internally).

You can use MDC/NCD values when you configure your log pattern (in logger configuration file). That way, each log will be annotated with your request id.